# A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time (UISegmentedControl)

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Hello The error occurs in the simulator on iOS 6.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'A view can only be associated with at most one view controller at a time! View <UIView: 0xa3ae880; frame = (0 0; 320 367); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xa3ae8e0>> is associated with <SearchHotelsViewController: 0xa3a6a20>. Clear this association before associating this view with <SecondViewController: 0xa1a9e90>.'

Initialization code

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Поиск туров", @"Выбор отеля", nil]];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
self.navigationItem.titleView = segmentedControl;

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(changeSegments:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
self.navigationItem.title = [segmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
[self setView:searchTours];

SearchHotelsViewController *searchHotelsController = [[SearchHotelsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchHotelsViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
selectHotels = searchHotelsController.view;
```

App crashes when `selected == 1` is `true`

```
-(void)changeSegments:(id)sender {
    NSInteger selected = [sender selectedSegmentIndex];
    if (selected == 0) {
        [self setView:searchTours];
    }
    if (selected == 1) {
        [self setView:selectHotels];
    }
    self.navigationItem.title = [sender titleForSegmentAtIndex:selected];
}
```

I cannot understand where the problem is.

SearchHotelsViewController.xib

[image: SearchHotelsViewController.xib]

Answer (score 24):

Make sure your ViewController does not contain another view controller object.  For example if your main view controller has a tableview, do not put the UITableViewController with in.  It this used to pass in iOS 5, but in iOS 6 they will not allow this.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into this when I was an idiot and dragged a "UITableViewController" object into the nib to serve as a view instead of a "UITableView". Whoops!

Comment: I did something similar, created a XIB and added a UIViewController->UIView instead of simply add the UIVIew...

Answer (score 14):

I also ran into this, here is my case.

For some convenience, I dragged a "UIViewController" object from storyboard into the nib file

**No need to delete and recreate.**

In the nib file, I dragged the view object from the controller object, then delete the controller object.

And set the view object outlet to **its real unique owner** "the viewController class", also in the nib.

[image: 111]

---

more details:

- raw, what you copied

[image: 111]

- step one, drag and delete

[image: 222]

- step two, link it

[image: 333]

- done, check it

[image: 666]

Answer (score 10):

I encountered this when I copied/pasted from a Storyboard into a xib file. Recreating the interface from the xib fixed this issue for me.

Comment: No need to recreate interface. Just drag 'View' out from 'ViewController' and link it to 'File's owner'. Don't forget to delete 'View Controller'

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Multiple xib files, some worked, some didn't, all had a single UITableView. I had to delete the broken xib files and create new files. After that they all worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to set a xib file to view controller, your xib file object must be window object not view controller and your xib file's owner class must be your target view controller class. Then you should add a relation between main view to file's owner outlets.